# Какой итерфейс веб-сервера на php и android приложения на html,css,javascript?

Tags: android

Есть приложение на javascript,html,css, разработанное под платформу андроид и веб сервер который должен получать запросы от этого приложения и на них отвечать. 
Как я понимаю существует какой-то интерфейс который позволяет это осуществить.
Что это за интерфейс и где о нем можно почитать?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST
Довольно популярный интерфейс на данный момент

Comment: Спасибо, очень похоже на то что искал, буду копать дальше в этом направлении)